# Centos You don't have permission

Tags: apache, jenkins, centos7

So my im having difficulties with a website server. When i try to access it, i get the error "You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server."
However i've given rights to the folders and the files exactly as ive done with a different server that does the same thing. Only way ive found to get rid of the error is with a command :

chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/

However the solution is not permanent, it seems to go away each time i use a jenkins build on the server.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect / servername
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost _default_:80>
  ServerName localhost
  <Location "/server-status">
    Require all granted
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 192.168****/23
    Allow from 192.168****
  </Location>
  ErrorLog logs/error.log
  SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" dontlog
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*internal dummy connection.*" dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined env=!dontlog
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Also, the same config and permissions work perfectly on a previous server that has been in use for a long time. Seems to be a problem from SElinux part.

Answer (score 0):

Problem diverted.

I managed to solve this by editing /etc/selinux/config file in Centos 7 and turn selinux disabled. Reboot and problem went away for good.